# openpose Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: cmake, linker, clang, caffe, openpose

I met an error when running

```
make -j`sysctl -n hw.logicalcpu`
```

to build openpose on maxos catalina:

```
[ 40%] Linking CXX shared library libopenpose.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "caffe::Net<float>::CopyTrainedLayersFrom(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      op::NetCaffe::initializationOnThread() in netCaffe.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[5]: *** [src/openpose/libopenpose.1.5.1.dylib] Error 1
make[4]: *** [src/openpose/CMakeFiles/openpose.dir/all] Error 2
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [openpose_lib] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/openpose_lib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

please help me if you guys know a little about this...

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
It turns out that the openpose built-in caffe is not working well. 
First install CAFFE independently outside openpose.
Second, when you are building openpose, turn BUILD_CAFFE flag to false in cmake and manually specify the path of CMAKE_INCLUDE directory and CMAKE_LIBS file in cmake.